# EBS detachment info

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

can we find which volumes were  detached from which instance in AWS.

I have detached some volumes except the root from an instance but i am not sure which volumes were previously attached to my instance.

Comment: Have you ever made an ami of the instance when the volumes were attached? Or don't the volumes have any tags from which you can get an idea? Otherwise , try cloudtrail. I will most certainly save your day!